# How to prevent NERDTree from opening the same file in different tabs?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

When I open a file in a tab with NERDTree by pressing `t`, is there anyway for NERDTree to not open the file if the file is already in a tab? Instead, I would like NERDTree to switch to that tab.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember that NERDTree respects this setting:

```
set switchbuf=useopen,usetab
```

See `:h switchbuf` for details.